# Assigning splitted string into substrings

Tags: c++, string, split

My problem is rather simple yet I can't get my head around it.

I was searching through the internet of course, but all solutions I found were using std::vectors and I'm not allowed to use them.

I have the following string:
`std::string str "Tom and Jerry";`

I want to split this string using space as a delimiter, and then assign the three words into three different strings.

```
//this is what I am trying to achieve
std::string substr1 = "Tom";
std::string substr1 = "and";
std::string substr1 = "Jerry";
```

This is how I am splitting the string by the space as a delimiter:

```
std::string buf;
std::string background;
std::stringstream ss(str);
while (ss >> buf) {
    if (buf == " ")
        background = buf; // don't really understand that part

std::cout << "splitted strings: " << buf << std::endl;
}
```

But I have no idea when and how should I assign the splitted strings into the substr1, substr2, substr3. Would anyone explain how should I throw in the strings assignment part into this?

I have tried some weird stuff like:

```
std::string substr1, substr2, substr3;
int counter = 1;
while (ss >> buf) {
    if (buf == " ")
        background = buf; // don't really understand that part

    counter = 1;
    if (counter == 1) {
        substr1 = buf;
        std::cout << "substr1 (Tom): " << substr1 << std::endl;
        counter++;
        }
    else if (counter == 2) {
        substr2 = buf;
        std::cout << "substr2 (and): " << substr2 << std::endl;
        counter++;
        }
    else if (counter == 3) {
        substr3 = buf;
        std::cout << "substr3 (Jerry): " << substr3 << std::endl;
        counter++;
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: This woul be simpler with an array of strings rather than 3 separate variables.

Comment: Don't set `counter = 1` inside the loop

Comment: buf will never be " ". That's the first thing. Second thing: simply write a function that takes a string, returns the first word in the string, and the rest of the string. Call it once, assign the the word to string1. One more time (using the rest of the string returned from the first call), assign the result to string2. And, for the ol' college try, a third time, and place the result in string3, discarding the rest. Mission accomplished! Wasn't that easy? Easiest. Homework. Assignment. Ever.

Comment: Why not just: `ss >> substr1;  ss >> substr2; ss >> substr3;` ?

Comment: @GeorgeGerganov wow, this is THAT simple. Thank you. I cannot accept your post because you replied as a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do `ss >> substr1; ss >> substr2; ss >> substr3;`. The `>>` operator works exactly with spaces as separator.

[Code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/08c362b7118fe40c)

Answer (score 0):

in "while"  ,when coming a space ,make it a substring before the space and the "tom and jerry" has 2 space so it was splitted to two words.  ss>>buf means input "ss"'s string to buf. so if there comes a spce it can store the word before space.